# Cordova Geofencing and iBeacon plugin conflict on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app built in Cordova running an iBeacon plugin (https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon).

I'm also trying to get geofencing working (using this plugin: https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence)

In iOS (9.1) the app will work if I use geofencing or iBeacons, but if I try to use both, it crashes when the iBeacon plugin starts monitoring for a region. The log shows this:

```
Process 736 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x8d0cf, 0x391ecc84 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x391ecc84 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x391ecc84 <+8>:  blo    0x391ecc9c                ; <+32>
    0x391ecc88 <+12>: ldr    r12, [pc, #0x4]           ; <+24>
    0x391ecc8c <+16>: ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
    0x391ecc90 <+20>: b      0x391ecc98                ; <+28>
```

I'm not sure where to even begin with troubleshooting this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

When I run in xCode instead of installing from the command line the log output for the error shows this:

Could not cast value of type 'CLBeaconRegion' (0x3bfc3fc4) to 'CLCircularRegion' (0x3bfc3f9c).

This is happening in the GeoFence plugin (GeofencePlugin.swif) at this method:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
        let lat = (region as! CLCircularRegion).center.latitude
        let lng = (region as! CLCircularRegion).center.longitude
        let radius = (region as! CLCircularRegion).radius

        log("Starting monitoring for region \(region) lat \(lat) lng \(lng) of radius \(radius)")
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Edward, I have exactly the same issue. I am wondering if you have found a solution yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the title, this is due to the conflict between the two libraries. I have opened a [pull request](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/pull/177) for [this issue with](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/issues/166) a fix but there has not been much activity on that repository,

You can also [my fork for this plugin](https://github.com/n9986/cordova-plugin-geofence) to avoid this issue.